# Iterative equation solver in Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numerical-methods

In order to solve a equation where the left hand side appears under an integral on the right hand side:

$$
B(p^2) = C\int_0^{p^2}f_1\left(B(q^2),q^2\right)\mathrm{d}q^2 + C\int_{p^2}^{\Lambda^2} f_2\left(B(q^2),q^2\right)\mathrm{d}q^2
$$

I have written the following code to do solve this equation iteratively:

```
import numpy as np
import time

def solver(alpha = 2.):

    L2 = 1 # UV Cut-off
    N = 1000 # Number of grid points
    maxIter = 100 # Maximum no. of iterations

    # The grid on which the function is evaluated    
    p2grid = np.logspace(-10, 0, N, base=10)
    dq = np.array([0] + [p2grid[i+1]-p2grid[i] for i in range(len(p2grid)-1)])

    Bgrid = np.ones(N)
    Bgrid_new = np.empty(N) # Buffer variable for new values of B

    C = alpha / (4*np.pi)

    for j in range(maxIter):

        for i, p2 in enumerate(p2grid):           
            # If lower and upper limit of an integral are the same, set to 0           
            if i > 0:       
                n = i + 1
                int1 = np.add.reduce((p2grid[0:n] * 3*Bgrid[0:n] /\
                        (p2 * (p2grid[0:n] + Bgrid[0:n]**2))) * dq[0:n])
            else:
                int1 = 0

            if i < N - 1:
                int2 = np.add.reduce((3*Bgrid[i:] /
                            (p2grid[i:] + Bgrid[i:]**2)) * dq[i:])
            else:
                int2 = 0                   
            # Write new values to buffer variable
            Bgrid_new[i] = C * (int1 + int2)

        # Calculate relative error (take the maximum)
        maxError = np.max(np.abs((Bgrid - Bgrid_new)/Bgrid_new))
        # Copy values from buffer to working variable
        Bgrid = np.copy(Bgrid_new)
        # If the change in the last iteration was small enough, stop
        if (maxError < 10**-4):
            break

    print "Finished in", j+1, "iterations, relative error:", maxError   
    return p2grid, Bgrid/np.sqrt(L2)

t0 = time.clock()
p2grid, Bgrid = solver()
print "Time:", time.clock() - t0, " seconds"
```

I am wondering if there a speedups possible:

- I am using `np.add.reduce` instead of `np.sum`, which is about 0.2 secs faster on my system
- I tried to move the code where `int1` and `int2` are calculated to a separate function, no improvement here
- Using `[... for enumerate(p2grid)]` instead of the `for`-loop seems not be faster either
- The profiler says almost all time is still spent in the `reduce` method.

I can't see how this code can be optimized further (as most time is spent in a function of the NumPy lib), but I can't believe I wrote the most efficient code either.

If there are no optimizations possible at code level, is there anything else I should try or look into, like different interpreters or something like that?

Comment: The way you wrote your integrals doesn't quite make sense. What's the variable of integration? Is it _p_? If so, are you using _p_ both as a dummy variable and a limit?

Comment: Sorry, fixed it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need line continuation characters inside brackets.

After splitting up your `reduce` lines, `line_profiler` says most of your time is actually in

```
(p2grid[0:n] * 3*Bgrid[0:n] / (p2 * (p2grid[0:n] + Bgrid[0:n]**2))) * dq[0:n]
```

and

```
(3*Bgrid[i:] / (p2grid[i:] + Bgrid[i:]**2)) * dq[i:]
```

Extracting those outside of the loop and pulling a division out of the sum:

```
t2 = dq * 3 * Bgrid / (p2grid + Bgrid**2)
t1 = t2 * p2grid

for i, p2 in enumerate(p2grid):           
    # If lower and upper limit of an integral are the same, set to 0           
    if i > 0:       
        int1 = np.add.reduce(t1[:i+1]) / p2
    else:
        int1 = 0

    if i < N - 1:
        int2 = np.add.reduce(t2[i:])
    else:
        int2 = 0                   

    # Write new values to buffer variable
    Bgrid_new[i] = C * (int1 + int2)
```

gives a good speed boost.

You can also simplify the logic to:

```
val = 0

if i > 0:       
    val = np.add.reduce(t1[:i+1]) / p2

if i < N - 1:
    val += np.add.reduce(t2[i:])

Bgrid_new[i] = C * val
```

But then note you have a sliding summation; you can do this beforehand with `numpy.add.accumulate`.

```
    t2 = dq * 3 * Bgrid / (p2grid + Bgrid**2)
    t1 = t2 * p2grid

    val1_accumulate = np.add.accumulate(t1)
    val2_accumulate = np.add.accumulate(t2[::-1])[::-1]

    for i, p2 in enumerate(p2grid):           
        # If lower and upper limit of an integral are the same, set to 0           
        val = 0

        if i > 0:
            val = val1_accumulate[i] / p2

        if i < N - 1:
            val += val2_accumulate[i]

        # Write new values to buffer variable
        Bgrid_new[i] = C * val
```

This is much faster.

Now this loop can probably be vectorized.

```
Bgrid_new = np.zeros_like(Bgrid)
Bgrid_new[+1:] += val1_accumulate[+1:] / p2grid[+1:]
Bgrid_new[:-1] += val2_accumulate[:-1]
Bgrid_new *= C
```

All in all, this seems to be a factor of 300-400 faster. You can do other optimizations like

```
dq = np.zeros_like(p2grid)
dq[1:] = np.diff(p2grid)
```

and removing the call to `copy`, but it should already be fast enough.

Then you should focus on cleaning up the code. Spacing is important as are appropriate variable names (`snake_case` and not-single-letter names). The trick is to make comments redundant:

```
num_grid_points = 1000 # Number of grid points
```

Note how the comment can now be removed.

Here's an attempt at a cleaner version. I've also added a couple more speed improvements, because I'm a hopeless addict:

```
def solver(alpha = 2.):
    uv_cutoff = 1
    num_grid_points = 1000
    max_iterations = 100

    # The grid on which the function is evaluated    
    p2_grid = np.logspace(-10, 0, num_grid_points, base=10)

    dq = np.empty_like(p2_grid)
    dq[0], dq[1:] = 0, np.diff(p2_grid)

    b_grid = np.ones(num_grid_points)

    c = alpha / (4 * np.pi)

    for iteration_num in range(max_iterations):
        t2 = 3 * dq * b_grid / (p2_grid + b_grid*b_grid)
        t1 = t2 * p2_grid

        t1_cumsum = np.add.accumulate(t1)
        t2_cumsum = np.add.accumulate(t2[::-1])[::-1]
        t1_cumsum[0] = t2_cumsum[-1] = 0

        b_grid_new = c * (t1_cumsum / p2_grid + t2_cumsum)

        # Calculate relative error (take the maximum)
        max_error = np.max(np.abs((b_grid - b_grid_new) / b_grid_new))

        b_grid = b_grid_new

        if max_error < 10**-4:
            break

    print "Finished in", iteration_num + 1, "iterations, relative error:", max_error   
    return p2_grid, b_grid / np.sqrt(uv_cutoff)
```

I'm not really sure how to rename these, though, because I'm not familiar with the maths.

Comment: This is truly incredible. Did not know about `accumulate` before. Well, thank you.